# Error while flushing Couchbase Database .Net

Tags: couchbase

I want to delete all the document from bucket.What have done so far is as below.

```
 var configuration = new ClientConfiguration
        {
            Servers = new List<Uri>
             {
                 new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["couchbaseServer"])
             }
        };

        using (var cluster = new Cluster(configuration))
        {
            using (var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("Bucket Name"))
            {
                bucket.CreateManager(userName, password).Flush();
            }
        }
```

When I execute this code I get error after sometime **"Error while copying content to a stream"**.

After that when i check log in couchbase error log it shows **"Flushing "bucketName" failed with error: 
{error,{flush_wait_failed,['ns_1@127.0.0.1'],[]}}"**

When I dig out little I found following error ***"Unable to read data from the transport connection:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. couchbase"***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default couchbase collections are not allowing to perform a flush, and this is visible pretty clear via the UI.

[image]

You should have some parameter like Flush.enable that you should set to true before you can actually flush the connection.

Comment: Thank you Tata but I already enabled flush at a time of bucket creation but still it's not working. So I prefer to delete and recreate the bucket and its working fine.